# I want to limit 3+ select boxes to only pick one <option> once - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I set up my jQuery [like so](http://jsbin.com/afudo3/8/edit).

It successfully lets me pick an option only once throughout the 3 dropdowns.

However, if I remove a dropdown (use the convenient button), an option is forever disabled (greyed out).

You'll see what I mean. First, ensure that it works and you can not select the same option more than once.

Now, remove and notice that one has been disabled, and it can never be selected again.

I don't know why it is forever greying out my option? It seems to keep picking it up when making the `selectedIndexes` array.

Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Comment: I selected `1` in all three drop downs successfully.

Comment: @Amarghosh Can you please elaborate for me ? Did you have JavaScript disabled? Better still, post an answer, if it's useful I'll vote it up. Cheers.

Comment: @alex: remove the `console.log` line, it throws me an error within jsbin and breaks the javascript. I guess Amarghosh has the same issue.

Comment: @jAndy It is meant to use a console if defined, or if not use the JSbin debugger. You can press "edit" in the top right corner and remove it to test.

Comment: @jAndy When I change the code in JSbin, and the title says 'unsaved', is there a way to save it without making a new revision?

Comment: @alex: unsure, I always create a new revision. Anyway I have to clear my browsers cache before I can load/see it afterwards. I actually hate jsbin for that :p

Comment: @Reigel I might start doing that, it looks a little easier to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made some changes to your code, you can see them [here](http://jsbin.com/afudo3/9/edit). It also did not work for my in the beginning, but now it works, I think, as expected. If you have questions, just comment :)

---

Here we go:

Redeclare the `$selects` array once you remove an element. The reference to the element is still in the array, so when you later compute the selected indexes, it will still be there!

```
select.next('button').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        select.remove();
       $(this).remove();
       $selects = $('select');  // <-- redeclare selects here, one is gone!
});
```

In the select click handler, use `nth-child` instead of `eq`. The former one will select all `option`s that are the `i`th child of their parents. Whereas `eq` will only select the `i`th element from the set of matched elements (i.e. it will only return one element). Note that the index of `nth-child` is one-based.

```
// Remove them from this dropdown
$.each(selectedIndexes, function(i, index) {

  // use n-th child here to get the child of each select.
  // eq only selects the element from the matched set
  $thisSelect.find('option:nth-child('+(index+1)+')').attr("disabled","disabled");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add code to this function to remove the related value from the array of selected values:

```
select.next('button').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        select.remove();
       $(this).remove();

  });
```

Alternatively, you could add an array to track the value that was selected in the dropdown being removed at the time of removal, and then exclude those values from the other function, where you grey out values that are used.

Answer (score 1):

## [demo](http://jsbin.com/afudo3/11/edit)

it's because of this line, `var $selects = $('select');`.

yes you removed the `select` element but not on that `var $selects`.

this will fixed it...

```
   select.remove();
   $(this).remove();
   $selects = $selects.not(select);
```

or

like this,

```
   $(this).remove();
   $selects = $selects.not(select.remove());
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I was going to point out as the other answers did that you need to "recollect" your `$select` variable to have the most current items. However, your script failed for me so I took a different approach. Below is my code. You can [also demo it here](http://jsbin.com/afudo3/10/edit) and a fully commented version [is available here](https://gist.github.com/d94ce2bb01b2b70c4c8b).

```
var $selects = $('select');

$selects
  .after('<button>remove</button><br /><br />')
  .each(function(i, el) {
    $(this)
      .next()
      .click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(el).remove();
        $(this).remove();

        $selects = $('select');
        $selects.change(); 
      });
    })
  .change( function() {
    $selects
      .children().removeAttr("disabled").end()
      .each(function(i, el){
        $selects
          .not(this)
          .find(':selected')
          .each(function(){ 
            $(el).find('option')
                 .eq($(this).index())
                 .attr('disabled', true);
          });                                                             
      });
    })
  .change();
```

​

Answer (score 0):

even after removing select element `$selects` array contained reference to it. I've modified `$selects.each` function:

```
$selects.each(function() {
        var select = $(this);
        select.next('button').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $selects=$selects.not(select);//ADDED THIS LINE

        select.remove();
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```